# How to use different assets for flutter flavor implementation?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a flutter app on which I am want to set up 3 flavors. Each one of them is having different font, different set of images and different set of string file.
How can I use particular font, images and String file for that particular flavor?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Follow [Github Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21682).
This is not implemented yet (Flutter 3.7.0 stable now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create app config file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum Flavor { FLAV1, FLAV2 }

class AppConfig extends InheritedWidget {
  final String appTitle;
  final String buildFlavor;
  final Flavor flavor;
  final Widget child;
  final ThemeData themeData;
  final String s3BucketURL;
  final String stripeKey;

  AppConfig(
      {@required this.appTitle,
      @required this.buildFlavor,
      @required this.themeData,
      @required this.flavor,
      @required this.s3BucketURL,
      @required this.stripeKey,
      @required this.child});

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(covariant InheritedWidget oldWidget) => false;

  static AppConfig of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType();
  }
}
```

create folders
assets/
assets/1/
assets/2/

add to pubspec.yaml

and you can use the indexs of flavors to get assets when accessing those.

```
SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/${AppConfig.of(context).flavor.inex}/splash_logo.svg',
                    colorBlendMode: BlendMode.srcIn,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  )
```

You can add different app config files when init. create different main files like main_flav1.dart, main_flav2.dev.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var configureApp = AppConfig(
    appTitle: 'App staging',
    buildFlavor: 'Staging',
    flavor: Flavor.FLAV1,
    themeData: PreOrderTheme.flav1Theme,
    stripeKey: 'pk_s',
    s3BucketURL: 'https://sssss.net',
    child: PreOrderApp(repository: Repository(baseURL:"https://webapi.net/api")),
  );
  return runApp(configureApp);
}
```

please refer https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b.

Comment: But all the assets will be loaded in apps and increasing their sizes...

Comment: Flutter provides a native way to do just that https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors#conditionally-bundling-assets-based-on-flavor

Answer (score 0):

From usage perspective, it is good. Is there a way to keep only required assets folder in the apk & remove the unwanted one?
There is a bug reported to have this features enabled from Flutter but it is closed without any resolution provided.